# Creating Widget via CMS > Widget - Widget only renders on certain block references

Tags: widget, ee-1.14

I am digging through my XML layouts for references to widgets and have found app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/layout/widget.xml (this is the parent of my layout). Everything within  were commented out but uncommenting the node didn't help.

How do I ensure that the block reference I want the widget to display in displays?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are not seeing the widget in the block that you are referring, chances are that the sort order is the same as some other widget, check if there is any other widget which is having the same sort order. If there exists a widget with same sort order then change it to the order in which you want the widgets to be displayed. Below is the illustration where to set the order

[image]